# Does polyamide react with hydrocarbons (group III engine oil) in its thermoplastic state?

Tags: polymers, fuel, amides

I need to form (bend) thermoplastic polyamide hose in rubber jacket to a desired shape.

I can use heat gun but I thought for better results I could use heated to 150C group III engine oil (your standard hydrocracked oil -> so called full-synthetic) to evenly distribute heat.

My question is does polyamide in its soft state reacts with petroleum product such as engine oil?

Comment: It certainly doesn't *react*, but perhaps could start to absorb it, or even dissolve a bit in it (if it's Nylon 11 you mention in newer question).